# Ubuntu 22 server slow to login and execute sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

On several servers running Ubuntu-server 22 we have the problems that some commands take a very long time to execute. These commands include ssh login as well as sudo commands. Everything not evolving rights seems to work normally. I am concentrating on the sudo aspect, hoping that it is representative for both issues.

I saw in other serverfault questions that this can be either due to /etc/hosts missing the hostname or a problem in /etc/resolv.conf. Both seems to be correct in our case and the setup the same way as on our workstations where we don't have that problem.

Other entries suggest the use of strace can shed light on our problem. I am using

```
/usr/bin/time sudo strace -t -o trace.log sudo echo hi
hi
0.00user 0.00system 1:12.73elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 11576maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+937minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I noticed now that strace itself shows no slowness. The start:

```
11:48:13 execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "echo", "hi"], 0x7ffd4e6007c8 /* 22 vars */) = 0
```

is at the same time as end of the execution:

```
11:48:13 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

However, the first entry is actually over a minute after the actual start of the execution of the command (which was directly when the clock turned 11.47), so something is slowing it down before strace shows anything, but I don't know what happens. The time command shows as well that it took over a minute to execute in wall time.

System is fully updated to newest version. We see this behavior on several servers.

**Edit**
Based on [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1110175/ubuntu-22-server-slow-to-login-and-execute-sudo#comment1449888_1110175) I rerun the strace command. The last entry before a long gap is at 14.02.07. The next entry when I logout at 14.04. However the shell itself can only be used from 14.03.03 on.

```
14:02:07.377486 ppoll ...
14:04:22.495075 --- SIGCHLD ...
```

It might be that the interesting things are happening then in a sshd child process. But `ps` is one of the programs that is slow as well (even as root) so I cannot geht the pid in time

Comment: *I  noticed now that strace itself shows no slowness.*  `/usr/bin/time sudo strace -t -o trace.log sudo echo hi` doesn't capture the full login/sudo process that usually includes the creation of a login shell.  As root, use something like `strace -tt -T -f -o trace.log -p [SSHD PID]` and trace an actual `ssh` login.  **BE CAREFUL**:  This will likely also capture the user's password.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the command `domainname` and see if there is any undesired output.
Normally, it should return "(none)". Otherwise you can check if the content in file `/etc/defaultdomain` contains correct value.